# rest api response format

Tags: json, rest, api, resources, restful-architecture

Should I treat all api response as "resource" and return a JSON object or simple array would be appropriate as well ?

for instance are all of the below responses valid?

`GET /rest/someresource` should return collection of ids

1. `[{id:1},{id:2}]`
2. `{{id:1},{id:2}}`
3. `[1,2]`

`GET /rest/someresource?id>0` search for ids bigger than zero and return collection of ids

1. `[{id:1},{id:2}]`
2. `{{id:1},{id:2}}`
3. `[1,2]`

Comment: What do you mean "simple array would be appropriate as well"?

Comment: How is `{{id:1},{id:2}}` a valid JSON?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Collection Resources

It is acceptable to return an array of resources - either a list of ids, or object structures - such a thing is commonly known as a 'collection' resource.

See http://51elliot.blogspot.com.au/2014/06/rest-api-best-practices-4-collections.html for an examination of resources and collections.

While not required by REST, it's common to use a plural noun to refer to a collection resource - e.g.

```
/rest/someresources
```

REST also requires the use of defined media types, and there are a couple available to assist with collections, e.g.:

- [Collection+json](https://github.com/collection-json/spec)

  - Provides a structure with meta data around a list of items wherein you define the structure of each item as your resource
- [HAL](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-kelly-json-hal-08)

  - provides a structure with embedded collections and embedded resources

And [many more](https://sookocheff.com/post/api/on-choosing-a-hypermedia-format/)

All provide a defined structure for including hypermedia links for your resource, or each resource in your collection - and if you are doing REST this is one of the things that the spec says you MUST do (even though many people don't).

### Your Proposed Json Structures

Some more specific comments on your proposed json structures:

Option 2 is not valid json.  Consider:

```
{{id:1},{id:2}}
```

A json object must have a name:value pair, e.g.

```
{somename:{id:1},someothername:{id:2}}
```

would be valid - but not very useful!

Also - strictly for json, the name should be enclosed in quotes.  the value may be enclosed in quotes if it is a string.

So if you don't want to use a commonly used media type as referenced above, your options are 1 or 3. which should be:

- `[{"id":1},{"id":2}]`
- `[1, 2]`

Both are valid, however option 1 will give you more flexibility to add more properties to each element of the array if you decide in the future you would like to return more than an id.  e.g. at some point in the future you might decide to return:

```
[{"id":1,"name":"fred"},{"id":2,"name":"wilma"}]
```

Option 3 will only ever be able to return a list of ids.

So personally I would go with option 1.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on how [RESTful](http://martinfowler.com/articles/richardsonMaturityModel.html#level1) you're aiming to be.

In addition to what @Chris Simon said, I'll add that if the server would only return IDs at `GET /rest/someresource`, the client would have to repeatedly call something like `GET /rest/someresource/{id}` in order to obtain data (it can display on the UI), right? This in turn would just increase the load on the server. If the id would be enough, you can probably get away with the proposed solution.

Also, once you decide you'd better be consistent.

Given that the 2nd option is not even valid, and the last is pretty limiting, I'd also go for the first option, JSON.

Answer (score 0):

Just to make it clear we are talking about different representations of the same resource here:

By `GET /rest/someresource` both `[{id:1},{id:2}]` and `[1,2]` are valid responses, but you should make clear which one you want to see, e.g. with the [prefer header](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7240). So by `Prefer: return=minimal` you would return `[1,2]` and if the header is not present, then `[{id:1},{id:2}]`. Just make sure that the prefer header is registered by the [vary header](https://www.fastly.com/blog/best-practices-for-using-the-vary-header), or you will have caching troubles.

By `GET /rest/someresource?id>0` you filter your collection. So either the `/rest/someresource?id>0` URI identifies a different filtered collection resource or it identifies the same collection resource, but with the filter query string your client indicates that it is waiting for a filtered representation of the resource and not the full representation. You can use the same by the minimal representation if you don't want to use the prefer header: `GET /rest/someresource?return=minimal`.

Note that if you want your client to query again, then you should send them hyperlinks in your response. The REST client must get the URIs (or URI templates) from these hyperlinks and it should not start to build URIs on its own.